# Isomorphism by classification

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question

Are there any examples other than using dimension for vector spaces where the easiest way to show that two objects are isomorphic is by using a classification theorem and showing that they must both be in the same class?  (homeomorphisms count too)

Comment: Finite sets, of course.  

Comment: Finite fields, algebraically closed fields, Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this question. Metamathematically speaking, isn't that a standard situation? Typically, a classification scheme (if available) involves constructing a robust set of invariants and isomorphism of two general objects is checked by computing and comparing them.

Comment: That's not the situation for isomorphism of groups given by presentations. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genus for surfaces would be a simple example.

Connectedness for compact $1$-dimensional manifolds would be another!